# How to optimize Mathematica code that depends on eigenvalues of big matrices and big sums?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, summation

I've been using Mathematica recently to generate some plots of a few functions. I've been able to get it right after a few questions here.

The resulting code, which works, is this:

```
M00[nmax_Integer,t_] := SparseArray[Band[{1,1}] -> Table[t^(2n), {n,0,nmax}]]
M11[nmax_Integer,t_] := (1-t^2)*SparseArray[Band[{1,1}] -> Table[n*t^(2(n-1)), {n,0,nmax}]]
M01[nmax_Integer,t_] := Sqrt[1-t^2]*SparseArray[Band[{1,2}] -> Table[Sqrt[n+1]*t^(2n), {n,0,nmax-1}], {nmax+1,nmax+1}]
M10[nmax_Integer,t_] := Transpose[M01[nmax,t]]

rhoplus[nmax_Integer,t_,th_] := (1-t^2)/2*((1+Cos[th])*M00[nmax,t]+(1-Cos[th])*M11[nmax,t]+Sin[th]*(M10[nmax,t]+M01[nmax,t]))
rhominus[nmax_Integer,t_,th_]:= (1-t^2)/2*((1-Cos[th])*M00[nmax,t]+(1+Cos[th])*M11[nmax,t]-Sin[th]*(M10[nmax,t]+M01[nmax,t]))

s[x_] = Piecewise[{{x*Log[2,x], 0<x<1}}]
EntropyPlus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := Total[s /@    Eigenvalues[rhoplus[nmax,t,th]]]
EntropyMinus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := Total[s /@ Eigenvalues[rhominus[nmax,t,th]]]

SumAuxElement[t_][n_Integer] := ((1 - t^2)/2)*t^(2 n)*(1 + (n + 1) (1 - t^2))
SumAuxList[nmax_Integer, t_] := Array[SumAuxElement[t], nmax + 1, {0, nmax}]
SumAux[t_,nmax_Integer]:=Total[s /@ SumAuxList[nmax, t]]

Discord[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := 1 + SumAux[t,nmax] - 1/2 (EntropyPlus[nmax, t, th] + EntropyMinus[nmax, t, th])

Plot[Discord[300, Tanh[r], Pi/2], {r, 0, 2.5}]
```

It works nice, but in my computer it takes forever to run depending on `nmax`. Indeed for `nmax = 300` it takes several minutes to generate the plot. If I need additional plots of things that are written in terms of the same `Discord` function, soon it becomes unmenageable to work with this.

I wanted to optimize this code, in order to get something faster.

First intuitively speaking, I do notice what perhaps is the biggest two problems:

1. First every time a plot like that is run, the eigenvalues are recomputed for several values of `t`. This seems to be the greater cause of less of performance.
2. A second issue is that the sums are recomputed everytime for all values of `t` needed in the plot and the sums do take some time.

The first issue I believe somehow the ideal thing would be to in the beginning of the code compute the eigenvalues for a range of `t` once and for all and have it already saved to be used later. I don't know how to do it though.

So, using this code as an example, when I have code that needs to perform computations with eigenvalues of big matrices and evaluate big sums like this to generate plots, how can I optmize the code so that it runs faster?

**Edit:** I've tried out the proposals on the answers, and although both of them give faster results as expected, both in my computer changed a piece of the plot and generated some warnings. The last full code I've tried is this:

```
range[nmax_] := range[nmax] = Range[0, nmax] // N

tab1[nmax_Integer, t_] := tab1[nmax, t] = t^(2. range[nmax])
tab2[nmax_Integer, t_] := tab2[nmax, t] = # t^(2. (# - 1.)) &@range[nmax]
tab3[nmax_Integer, t_] := tab3[nmax, t] = Sqrt[# + 1.] t^(2. #) &@Most[range[nmax]]

xM00[nmax_Integer, t_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> tab1[nmax, t]]
xM11[nmax_Integer, t_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> (1. - t^2.) tab2[nmax, t]]
xM01[nmax_Integer, t_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 2}] -> Sqrt[1. - t^2.] tab3[nmax, t], {nmax + 1, nmax + 1}]
xM10[nmax_Integer, t_] := Transpose[xM01[nmax, t]]

xrhoplus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := (1. - t^2.)/2. ((1. + Cos[th]) xM00[nmax, t] + (1. - Cos[th]) xM11[nmax, t] + Sin[th] (xM10[nmax, t] + xM01[nmax, t]))
xrhominus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := (1. - t^2.)/2. ((1. - Cos[th]) xM00[nmax, t] + (1. + Cos[th]) xM11[nmax, t] - Sin[th] (xM10[nmax, t] + xM01[nmax, t]))

cs = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, If[0. < x < 1., x Log[2, x], 0.], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    Parallelization -> True]

xEntropyPlus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := Total[cs@Eigenvalues[xrhoplus[nmax, t, th], Method -> "Banded"]]
xEntropyMinus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := Total[cs@Eigenvalues[xrhominus[nmax, t, th], Method -> "Banded"]]

xSumAuxElement = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {n, _Real,1}}, ((1. - t^2.)/2.) t^(2. n) (1. + (n + 1.) (1. - t^2.)), CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True]

xSumAuxList[nmax_Integer, t_] := xSumAuxElement[t, range[nmax]]

xSumAux[t_, nmax_Integer] := Total[cs@xSumAuxList[nmax, t]]

xDiscord[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := 1 + xSumAux[t, nmax] - 1/2 (xEntropyPlus[nmax, t, th] + xEntropyMinus[nmax, t, th])

Plot[xDiscord[300, Tanh[r], Pi/2.], {r, 0, 2.5}]
```

The output then is the following:

[image]

So there are some warning messages and the piece of the plot to the left of 0.5 vanished. Is this perhaps something about my computer or am I missing something of the code?

I have further evaluated `CompilePrint@cs` and got:

```
    1 argument
    1 Boolean register
    1 Integer register
    6 Real registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking on
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}

    R0 = A1
    R2 = 1.
    I0 = 2
    R3 = 7.
    R1 = 0.
    Result = R4

1   B0 = R1 < R0 < R2 (tol R3)
2   if[ !B0] goto 7
3   R4 = Log[ I0, R0]
4   R5 = R0 * R4
5   R4 = R5
6   goto 8
7   R4 = R1
8   Return
```

Answer (score 7):

## The eigensolver

The default eigensolver method for `SparseArrays` is  `"Arnoldi"`; it is not good at computing the whole spectrum of an operator. Luckily, you matrices are tridiagonal, so you can use a banded solver. So, better use

```
EntropyPlus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := 
 Total[s /@ Eigenvalues[rhoplus[nmax,t,th], Method -> "Banded"]]
EntropyMinus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := 
 Total[s /@ Eigenvalues[rhominus[nmax,t,th], Method -> "Banded"]]
```

This should get you rid of quite some message handling (precision issues). Moreover, it should be more accurate and faster, especially for larger matrices.

## Compiling some helper function

Using the following should also help. In particular, `cf` is implement such that underflow of machine precision numbers cannot happen.

```
cs = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
   If[0. < x < 1., x Log2[x], 0.],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
EntropyPlus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := 
 Total[cs@Eigenvalues[rhoplus[nmax, t, th], Method -> "Banded"]]
EntropyMinus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := 
 Total[cs@Eigenvalues[rhominus[nmax, t, th], Method -> "Banded"]]
cf = With[{threshold = 0.5 Log[$MinMachineNumber]},
   Compile[{{t, _Real}, {n, _Integer}},
    Block[{x},
     If[Log[t] (2 n) < threshold,
      0.,
      x = ((1. - t^2) 0.5) t^(2 n) (1. + (n + 1) (1. - t^2));
      If[0. < x < 1., x Log2[x], 0.]
      ]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ]
   ];
SumAux[t_, nmax_Integer] := Total[cf[t, Range[0, nmax]]]
```

Comment: Thanks @HendrikSchumacher ! I have two questions: the first of those is that with this specific method I got the message "The method "Banded" accepts only sparse matrices with elements that are machine-real or machine-complex numbers." and the plot now misses a part (from r = 0 to r = 0.9 the graph disappeared). Is something more that needs to be changed to use this method? The second question is: and in a more general context (not tridiagonal matrices) is there some general approach to get a faster code? For instance, my idea of "precomputing" the eigenvalues even makes some sense? Thanks!

Comment: "The method "Banded" accepts only sparse matrices with elements that are machine-real or machine-complex numbers." -- This indicates that you have tried to feed `Eigenvalues` with symbolic matrices. Maybe that is because `Plot` first tries to evaluate its first argument symbolically. You can prevent that by defining `Discord ` such that enforces numeric arguments to execute with `Discord[nmax_Integer, t_?NumberQ, th_?NumberQ] := ...`

Comment: Towards the second question: You have a two-parameter family of matrices. _Maybe_ that can be exploited in a way such that eigenvalue information can recycled or inexpensively compute from precomputed data. But that really depends on the family oft matrices. I don't know of a general way to do that.

Comment: Well, I'm giving to `Eigenvalues` the matrix `rhoplus[nmax,t,th]`. I think that somehow by standard Mathematica evaluates this a symbolic matrix and then later feeds the values. I tried redefining `Discord` as you said and further redefined all the functions definitions to use `t_?NumberQ` and `th_?NumberQ` but the message persists. Do you have any idea what may be wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Are `nmax`, `t`, `th` really numeric? Notice that I meant to add `Method -> "Banded"` into your preexisting code. Executing `Eigenvalues[rhoplus[nmax, t, th], Method -> "Banded"]` as standalone will (of course) produce nonsense...

Comment: I added the `Method -> "Banded` to my preexisting code. As for the parameters, it is like the `Plot` call in the OP: `nmax` is set to `300` when running the plot function, as well as `th` which is set to `Pi/2`. The `t` parameter is set equal to `Tanh[r]` and the later parameter varies in `{r,0,2.5}`. I've even trying to use `N[Pi]` and `N[Tanh[r]]` but didn't help. Since I'm new to Mathematica I believe I'm missing something **very** basic here.

Comment: Just as a side question: Which version of _Mathematica_ do you use?

Comment: It is version 11.2

Answer (score 2):

1. the `Mxx` functions waste time with `Table`; instead use an appropriate `Range` for *all* of them; additionally, use *memoization* (probably helpful...); use the modified `Mxx`'s to define modified versions of `rhosign` functions:

   ```
   (* the utility of N will become apparent later *)
   range[nmax_] := range[nmax] = Range[0, nmax] // N

   (* tables needed to define the Mxx functions *)
   tab1[nmax_Integer, t_] := tab1[nmax, t] = t^(2. range[nmax])
   tab2[nmax_Integer, t_] := tab2[nmax, t] = # t^(2. (# - 1.)) &@range[nmax]
   tab3[nmax_Integer, t_] := tab3[nmax, t] = Sqrt[# + 1.] t^(2. #) &@Most[range[nmax]]

   (* the modified Mxx functions using the tables above, that in turn use range *)
   xM00[nmax_Integer, t_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> tab1[nmax, t]]
   xM11[nmax_Integer, t_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> (1. - t^2.) tab2[nmax, t]]
   xM01[nmax_Integer, t_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 2}] -> Sqrt[1. - t^2.] tab3[nmax, t], {nmax + 1, nmax + 1}]
   xM10[nmax_Integer, t_] := Transpose[xM01[nmax, t]]

   (* the rhosign modified functions *)
   xrhoplus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := (1. - t^2.)/ 2. ((1. + Cos[th]) xM00[nmax, t] + (1. - Cos[th]) xM11[nmax, t] + Sin[th] (xM10[nmax, t] + xM01[nmax, t]))
   xrhominus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := (1. - t^2.)/ 2. ((1. - Cos[th]) xM00[nmax, t] + (1. + Cos[th]) xM11[nmax, t] - Sin[th] (xM10[nmax, t] + xM01[nmax, t]))
   ```
2. use `Compile` to define the `Entropysign` functions, as already suggested in the answer by **Henrik Schumacher**:

   ```
   cs = Compile[{{x, _Real}},

     If[0. < x < 1., x Log[2, x], 0.],

     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True
    ]

   (* Use Method -> "Banded" for Eigenvalues as suggested by **Henrik Schumacher** *)
   xEntropyPlus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := Total[cs@Eigenvalues[xrhoplus[nmax, t, th], Method -> "Banded"]]
   xEntropyMinus[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := Total[cs@Eigenvalues[xrhominus[nmax, t, th], Method -> "Banded"]]
   ```
3. use `Compile` to assist the `SumAux` functions:

   ```
   (* the second argument for this function makes use of the fact that range is N - see below *)
   xSumAuxElement = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {n, _Real, 1}},

     ((1. - t^2.)/2.) t^(2. n) (1. + (n + 1.) (1. - t^2.)),

     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     Parallelization -> True
    ]

   xSumAuxList[nmax_Integer, t_] := xSumAuxElement[t, range[nmax]]

   (* another point where Compile helps... *)
   xSumAux[t_, nmax_Integer] := Total[cs@xSumAuxList[nmax, t]]
   ```

Most of the work is done; all that's left is defining an appropriately modified main function (`Discord`) ie:

```
 xDiscord[nmax_Integer, t_, th_] := 1 + xSumAux[t, nmax] - 1/2 (xEntropyPlus[nmax, t, th] + xEntropyMinus[nmax, t, th])
```

Finally, evaluating `Plot[xDiscord[300, Tanh[r], Pi/2.], {r, 0, 2.5}]` returns almost instantly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user42582. It is much faster but I have two issues with it. The first is that I don't get theright plot. It misses a part, in other words, to the left of something around 0.5 in the x axis, the plot vanishes. A second issue is that a get a few warning messages: "Eigenvalues: The method "Banded" accepts only sparse matrices with elements that are machine-real or machine-complex numbers" and "CompiledFunction: Argument Eigenvalues[SparseArray[Automatic,<<3>>],Method->Banded] at position 1 should be a machine-size real number". Any idea why it doesn't fully work in my computer?

Comment: @user1620696 I'm not sure what's wrong; I have just rechecked the code in my answer and everything evaluates without generating messages; please give a detailed account of the code you used and relevant input

Comment: I've added one edit with the code I've ran and the output. The code I've tried is basically yours, since it worked perfectly for you. There are some warnings and the plot misses one piece. Is this perhaps something related to my computer or am I missing something about the code proposal? I think this is not about the code, since I've tried exactly the one which works for you.

Comment: @user1620696 I've run the code you provided in the edit-which actually seems identical to the code in my answer, like you said-and I encounter *no* message or plot problems; if the problem persists even after a clean run (quitting the kernel and evaluating everything on a fresh kernel) then the most probable culprit I can think of is some issue with `Compile`; please evaluate the following and report back : load package << "CompiledFunctionTools`"  and then evaluate eg CompilePrint@cs

Comment: I have evaluated the code you mention and posted the output. By the way the compiler I'm using is the Visual Studio compiler. I have it in my machine because I work with Visual Studio as well, and thought it would be enough for Mathematica as well. Is perhaps the compiler the problem ?

Comment: @user1620696 from what I can gather, you have a working compiler; if it is the case that the errors persist even after quitting all live kernels, starting a fresh one and evaluating the code, then I would suggest testing every intermediate function *manually* until you can pinpoint which one is broken; I cannot reproduce the error so I cannot be of much help; every function I replaced with a new version was checked against its previous implementation and *no* test case returned an error; I can re-check my code but I'll have to get back to you on that;